# Intellij exclude single file from module output

Tags: intellij-idea

How to exclude a single file from module output? I have seen the field "excluded files" in the module configuration (File -> Project structure -> modules) and tried to enter a pattern like that one:

path\to\file\*Server*

in order to exclude the class

```
path.to.file.MyServer
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Excludes and add your file name to the list.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have done in this way at the moment, but I would prefer a solution directly in the module's definition

Comment: This is not supported. A module definition lists the directories included or excluded in the module; there is no way to include or exclude individual files.